# Access to database row in another thread during integration test

Tags: grails, grails-orm, integration-testing

I have a problem in a Grails 3.3.8 application after the upgrade from Grails 2.5.6.

I have a service which using `Row.findAll()` to get records from an H2 database. Then it creates a list of closures for future execution. Then the list is running by a `ThreadExecutor` via `invokeAll()`. In each closure I get data via `Row.findById()`.

It is working when I run program, but it does not work in integration tests. I checked that `Row.findAll().size()` returns 0 inside the closure but just before the `invokeAll()` it returns a positive number.

Update:

I prepare small test for that:

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class TestSpec extends Specification {
    void "test something"() {
        when:
            f()
        then:
            g()
    }
    private void f() {
        Raw raw = new Raw()
        raw.text = "text"
        raw.save(flush: true)
    }
    private void g() {
        Closure closure = {
            try {
                def x = rawService.getRawSize()
                if (x != 1) throw new Exception("A: x = " + x)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                throw e
            }
        }
        def x = rawService.getRawSize()
        executorService.invokeAll([closure])
    }
}
```

The code above is not working. It throws an Exception.

Comment: Are you creating test data in your test or is this already existing data?

Comment: I create data during the test. I run a service for that

Comment: Try wrapping the body of `f()` with `Raw.withNewSession { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the body of your `f()` method in a [`Raw.withNewSession`](https://docs.grails.org/3.3.8/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html) block. This will save your new instance in a separate session. After the closure is finished the session will close, persisting your instance and allowing it to be accessed in another session or thread.

```
private void f() {
    Raw.withNewSession {
        Raw raw = new Raw()
        raw.text = "text"
        raw.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```